# Trace does not create file for output

Tags: c#, trace

This is how trace listener defined in app.config:

```
  <system.diagnostics>
    <trace autoflush="true" indentsize="4">
      <listeners>
        <add name="Listener" type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener" initializeData="Import.log" traceOutputOptions="None" />
        <remove name="Default" />
      </listeners>
    </trace>
  </system.diagnostics>
```

And the simple method that calls `Trace.WriteLine`:

```
  public static void WriteLine(LogLevel logLevel, string message)
  {
       var message = String.Format("{0}", messageText);

       Trace.WriteLine(message);   
  }
```

But as a result - there is no file created and messages there. I thought that the reason could be in method that is calling outside of assembly. But that looks impossible.
Is there any additional settings that I missed? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Has application privileges for write to that path?

Comment: Yes, it's regular folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the problem was in that the static method with logging was invoking from another assembly. There are two solutions I've figured out:

- Make `app.config` copying after build (or copy manually) to the folder with assembly which contains
  that method;
- Declare diagnostics section with trace options in app.config of **executing** assembly.